# A book of set theory, exercise.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\{A_i\}_{i∈I}$ and $\{B_j \}_{j∈J}$ be indexed families of classes. Suppose that $∀i ∈ I, ∃j ∈ J$ such that $B_j ⊆ A_i$
. Prove
that $$\bigcap_{j\in J}B_j\subseteq \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$$

For this demo, I'm going to take a $ x \in \bigcap_ {j \in J} B_j $. So for all $ j \in J $ we have $ x \in B_j $. But how can I use my hypothesis to guarantee that my $ B_j \subseteq A_i $ for all $ i \in I $, and thus conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \bigcap_{j\in J} B_{j}$, then $x \in B_{j} \quad \forall \, j\in J$

And we have that for each $i\in I$ there exists some $j_{i}\in J $ such that $B_{j_{i}} \subset A_{i}$

Then for each $i \in I $ we have that $x \in B_{j_{i}} \subset A_{i} \implies x\in A_{i} \quad \forall \, i \in I$

Thus $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}$

Comment: thanks for help me in that problem. I appreciate it :).

Comment: It was a pleasure!